# Send Message to Friend On Facebook with C#

Tags: facebook, api

I am new on Facebook API. I want to send message to friend with facebook api. I am developing a desktop application in c#. And I used graph.facebook.com but I can see just some information. I think that to login facebook system and after send message some id. I looked developers.facebook.com but I didnt find useful information. Maybe I looked in wrong way..

I need some advice about it (how to login and send message)
I followed function of messange sendin on google chrome and I saw send.php worked . But I want to use Facebook API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design Facebook does not allow the API to send messages. You can post on the other users wall, or send them an email.

Comment: haha thanx.. I felt so stupid :) I was searching abotu it for long time.. Thank you again.